# Basic doubts about Nutch

Tags: lucene, indexing, nutch

right now i have a project in which i need to build a search engine, but i cannot use Solr, only nutch and lucece, tho while im searching in forums and such i find out alot of people saying nutch does the indexing, i installed nutch (1.4) and crawled data, but realized i got no index folder or something like that, only the crawled data.. So, the question is, does nutch actually index what it crawls or it needs Lucene for indexing and search?

PS. for this project, i cant use Solr, only pure nutch and lucene and i need to build everything using Java, so im really confused when people says that nutch does in fact index... Sorry for my bad english, its not my native language...

Answer (score 0):

Lucene is used for indexing and search by Nutch. As I understand Nutch, it passes the pages it finds to Lucene for indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Nutch will not index your data, it does not use Lucene so therefore it cannot create its own indexes.  Nutch must pass the documents to Solr for it to be indexed.

Check out : [nutch vs solr indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844792/nutch-vs-solr-indexing)